# How to incorporate this drop-down list into my program code VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following drop-down/combo box list that has two options, namely `Internal` and `External`. My drop-down list looks like this: [image]

And then I have a macro that runs through the following button: [image]

My question does not revolve around the actual content of the code but rather the structure of the code to include the drop-down list, so I have simplified it a lot for the sake of getting to the point. My (simplified) code initially made a rudimentary calculation.

```
Sub InsertEquitiesBonds(Dim x as Double, Dim y as Double)
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("PnL")
ws.Range("C4").Value = x + y
End Sub
```

I would like to create a decision logic in this code after clicking `populate`, so like:

```
If DropDown6_Change.Value = "Internal" Then
ws.Range("C4").Value = x + y 
Else 
ws.Range("C4").Value = x - y
End If
```

What do I need to use for the above code to be realized?

Answer (score 1):

Almost there.

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    x = 10
    y = 5
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Drop Down 1").ControlFormat
        Select Case .List(.Value)
        Case "Internal": ws.Range("C4").Value = x + y
        Case "External": ws.Range("C4").Value = x - y
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question: If I have a function `Fees(rng as Range)`, I would like to create a new function `Fees1(rng as Range, strng as String)` where strng is actually just string (i.e. either `internal` or `external` extracted from the DropDown List)... How do I call this function? `Fees1(ws.Range("C3").Value, ws.Shapes("Drop Down 1").Case)` ???

Comment: I don't understand the question.